# Al actualizar un Div con jQuery o AJAX me duplica la pagina

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Estoy intentando actualizar un div con jQuery  aquí el codigo javascript;

```
 <script> $(document).ready(function(){ setInterval(loadClima,5000);
 });

 function loadClima(){ $("#coches").load("dashboard.php"); } </script>
```

aqui pongo el div ;

```
 <div id="coches">  <?php
     $sql = "SELECT `id` FROM `vehicles` WHERE `active` >= '1' ;";
     $result_of_query = $db_link->query($sql);
    $total_records = mysqli_num_rows($result_of_query);    echo "<h1>" . $total_records . "</h1>";
        ?> Vehiculos Circulando</div>
```

Lo único que hace ese DIV es consultar a la base de datos los vehículos activos que están y con un echo pues los muestras, y lo que quisiera es que me los actualizase a los segundos con el código javascript y lo hace, pero a la vez me duplica la pagina.

PD; con Ajax me pasa exactamente lo mismo
Código ajax que he utilizado ( Obviamente no he utilizado los dos codigos a la vez );

```
 var seconds = 4; // intervalo de actualizar div
     var divid = "divevento"; // el div que quieres actualizar!
     var url = "proceso.php"; // el archivo de proceso php

     function objetoajax(){

         // The XMLHttpRequest object

         var xmlHttp;
         try{
             xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
         }
         catch (e){
             try{
                 xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); // Internet Explorer
             }
             catch (e){
                 try{
                     xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                 }
                 catch (e){
                     alert("Tu explorador no soporta AJAX.");
                     return false;
                 }
             }
         }

         // Timestamp for preventing IE caching the GET request
         var timestamp = parseInt(new Date().getTime().toString().substring(0, 10));
         var procesourl = url+"?t="+timestamp;

         // The code...

         xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
             if(xmlHttp.readyState== 4 && xmlHttp.readyState != null){
                 document.getElementById(divid).innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
                 setTimeout('objetoajax()',seconds*1000);
             }
         }
         xmlHttp.open("GET",procesourl,true);
         xmlHttp.send(null);
     }

     window.onload = function(){
         objetoajax(); // Ejecutamos objetoajax
      }
```

Ojala alguien pueda darme alguna solución de que podría ser, si hace falta

Answer (score 1):

Algo más limpio sería:

```
$("#coches").empty().load("dashboard.php");
```

Espero ser de ayuda, aun así mírate $.ajax()

Answer (score 0):

Pues efectivamente estas cargando lo que quieres en en tu elemento $("#coches"). Ahora, si lo que estas obteniendo debe remplazar lo que esta actualmente en dicho elemento. Debes asegurarte de limpiarlo antes, por ejemplo:

```
$("#coches").html('');
$("#coches").load ....
```

Ya que sino estarás apilando lo que recibes una y otra vez.